# How to declare a bulk collect into when I dont know how many columns I'll get - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm creating a dynamic query that have the columns "x , y, z, z1...zn" like this:

```
`TYPE VAR IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
tNIVEL                     VAR;
t_local_code       VAR;
tPERM                VAR;
tVAL_PERM          VAR;
temp1 VAR;
temp2 VAR;
temp3 VAR;
temp4 VAR;
temp5 VAR;
temp6 VAR;
temp7 VAR;
BEGIN
 vQuery:='select z.nivel, y.cod_local_perm, z.permiso,y.valor_permiso     valor_perm,';
 FOR i IN 2 .. p_checkboxes.COUNT LOOP
            IF i <> p_checkboxes.LAST THEN
             vQuery:=vQuery||' fun_perm_perm('||p_checkboxes(i)||',c.cod_local_perm ),';
            ELSE
             vQuery:=vQuery||' fun_perm_perm('||p_checkboxes(i)||',c.cod_local_perm )  ';
            END IF; 
            END LOOP;
               from (select distinct level NIVEL,a.COD_MASTER , b.cod_local_perm, lpad(chr(9),level,chr(9)) || replace(replace(replace(A.nom_permiso, '' " '' ,null) ,chr(10),null),chr(13),null) PERM  ';

 vQuery:=vQuery||'  from TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B
                WHERE B.COD_MASTER_SAP = A.COD_MASTER_SAP 
                and B.TIPO_SAP =''SAP_VIEJO'' 
                start with a.cod_master_sap_padre IS NULL 
                connect by prior a.COD_MASTER_SAP = a.cod_master_sap_padre ) z,  sap_perm_revisar y
                where    y.id_det = '||p_checkboxes(1)||'
                AND   y.cod_local_perm = z.cod_local_perm         
                order by y.cod_local_perm';
END;
`
```

The select is just an example in order to show you that I'll get a new column depending on the checkboxes my problem  is that when I execute the query doing this:

```
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vQuery
   BULK COLLECT INTO   tNIVEL,
                                   tNIVEL ,
                                   tPERM,
                                   tVAL_perm,
                                   temp1
                                   ...
                                   tempn;
```

-- I need to declare the same quantity of checkboxes I already select.

Please help me out.

Comment: What are you going to subsequently do with this data when you don't know how many collections you're going to end up with?  You're probably well into the point that it makes more sense to use `dbms_sql` rather than `execute immediate` to do your dynamic SQL.

Comment: Is maximum count of checkboxes is only seven? In this case you can always return 7 columns: || case when i > p_checkbox.count then ' null ' else 'func_perm_perm(....'  end

Comment: No it isn't, checkboxes could be more than 7. Actually this is my real problem. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Justin if the list of columns has no (reasonable) upper limit.

If it is a well defined list if columns and not too many of them, you could also just try generate a SQL statement that always fills up the list with dummy values like NULL.

Imagine the following 3 cases that always return 3 columns:

```
SELECT NULL, a2, a3 FROM myTable;
SELECT a1, a2, a3 FROM myTable;
SELECT a1, a2, NULL FROM myTable;
```